# Spring Boot @Async annotation w/ CompletableFuture on service or WebAsyncTask for async REST API to call another API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, spring-async

I'm unsure which approach I should take for an async REST API which will call another API and wait for results and respond to the original requester:

a) annotate service with `@Async` and use with `CompletableFuture`?

or

b) use `WebAsyncTaks` with async executor?

For now, I have a "dirty" way which simply implements `Runnable` on a service and then run the service in a separate thread as

```
MyService service = new MyService(someObject, url);

Thread t = new Thread(service);
t.start();
```